# Not able to return attribute for the for the nested key

Tags: python, json

I have a json in the following format.

```
json_tree = {
    "Gardens": {
        "Seaside": {
            "@loc": "porch",
            "@myID": "1.2.3",
            "Tid": "1",
            "InfoList": {
                "status": {
                    "@default": "0",
                    "@myID": "26"
                },
                "count": {
                    "@default": "0",
                    "@myID": "1"
                }
            },
            "BackYard": {
                "@myID": "75",
                "Tid": "2",
                "InfoList": {
                    "status": {
                        "@default": "6",
                        "@myID": "32"
                    },
                    "count": {
                        "@default": "0",
                        "@myID": "2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to return the "@loc" value when I search for the key 'Seaside" or "Backyard". I want it to be generic as the key could be any string.

Currently, I have the following method and it only returns me the "@loc" when I search for the "Seaside" and None when I search for "BackYard". Note "BackYard" has the same "@loc" as "Seaside" as it is nested inside it.

I am not sure what is missing in this code.

My implementation:

```
def getLoc(json_tree , key):
    for k1,v1 in json_tree.items():
        for k,v in v1.items():
            if '@loc' in v and v['@loc'] is not None and str(k) == key:
                return v['@loc']
```

```
The output should be "backyard" for the following example.
getLoc(json_tree, "Seaside")
getLoc(json_tree, "Backyard")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def get_vals(d, _key, _score = None):
   for a, b in d.items():
     if _key == a:
        yield b.get('@loc', _score)
     if isinstance(b, dict):
        yield from get_vals(b, _key, b.get('@loc', _score))
     elif isinstance(b, list):
        for i in b:
          yield from get_vals(i, _key, b.get('@loc', _score))

print(list(get_vals(json_tree, 'Seaside')))
print(list(get_vals(json_tree, 'BackYard')))
```

Output:

```
['porch']
['porch']
```

Comment: The keys could be any string and I pasted in the question the sample output I expect. Not sure if this answers it.

Comment: The "@loc" is only with the root node and the nested node also has the same attribute. So if I search for any nested keys, it should be associated with the same "@loc" attribute.

Comment: I get yield b["@loc"] unhandled exception when I run it. Do you get the same?

Comment: @LauraSmith Hmm. What is the exception?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197518/discussion-between-laura-smith-and-ajax1234).

Comment: Thank you @Ajax1234

Comment: I just had a quick question. For example, I modified your code to keep a track of the "@oid" values. For example, if search for the key, "Backyard", I should return a list with the following value, ["1.2.3.75.32"]  which is till the "@myID" value in its "status" node. I only get the 32. How do i store the route to this? We could continue in chat